# Open source libraries for asymmetric encryption for Android and iOS

Tags: open-source, encryption, mobile, cryptography, soap

I'm looking for open-source libraries for both Android and iOS (Swift) to help implement Asymmetric key encryption. I have the public Key and the library should help with AES-128 (data encryption) and RSA1.5 (Key Wrap Encryption).

This is to construct the SOAP request with WSSecurity implemented.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 0):

A good start for a cross platform crypto library is [Libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/), it supports state of the art cryptography. Since you asked for specific algorithms you could also try the [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) crypto API, though I'm not sure about compatibility with iOS.